# Possible to click button in web browser without opening page

Tags: c#, html, browser

Is is possible to click button without opening web page using c#?

I searched a lot of information in internet but can't find answear to this question.
For example when i have button like this : 
[image]

And now i just create a program with webbrowers and open my page etc. and then make this click. But can i do that without opening page just via only code? For example Do click in this class="btn btn-xs" and title = '"Skip"?
Can somene just explain possibility of this?

Comment: So you want to click the `button` without loading the web page first?

Comment: It depends what the button does really. The idea would be that instead of clicking the button you just replicate what the button click does. For example, if a button posts form data then your application would just post the form data directly and not load the page at all. In this case tough, it looks like it's javascript centic so not as simple. You would need to work out what the JS does, and then try to replicate that directly (I would imagine an ajax call of some sort perhaps). In this case, you need to know what `vm.skipTask()` does and try to replicate it

Comment: By default `Button` will submit the page. If you want it to just click, add the attribute `type='button'`

Comment: Yes i just want click button without loading page just have direct link and just want to press this button without any loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use headless browser's like CefSharp (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) offscreen mode and use JavaScript to invoke the click.
Here is [a minimal example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample) which enters `CefSharp Was Here!` in Google's searchbar. With similar approach you can invoke `ExecuteScriptAsync` and pass your JavaScript code as argument to Click on the button you identified.
I have used this in case where have no control over published content.